# Flag -useHCatalog not working

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera-cdh

I installed `CDH5.4` in single node following the instructions [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_qs_cdh5_pseudo.html), also, I put the `hive-metastore` in localmode using these [instructions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hive_metastore_configure.html)  and everything works perfectly, except when I tried to connect `pig` with the `metastore`:

```
➜  ~  pig -useHCatalog
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2015-05-01 15:45:08,657 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.4.0 (rUnversioned directory) compiled Apr 21 2015, 12:19:15
2015-05-01 15:45:08,658 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/itam/pig_1430495108571.log
2015-05-01 15:45:09,035 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:09,035 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:09,035 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost:8020
2015-05-01 15:45:09,940 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:09,941 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: localhost:8021
2015-05-01 15:45:09,941 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:09,999 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:10,001 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:10,088 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:10,089 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:10,125 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:10,126 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:10,160 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:10,162 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:10,194 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:10,195 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:10,227 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:10,228 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:10,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:10,262 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-05-01 15:45:10,295 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-05-01 15:45:10,296 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
```

and when I tried to access the table:

```
grunt> a = load 'ufos' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
2015-05-01 15:46:11,656 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/itam/pig_1430495108571.log
grunt>
```

Hadoop version

```
➜  ~  hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.0
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r c788a14a5de9ecd968d1e2666e8765c5f018c271 
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-04-21T19:16Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum cd78f139c66c13ab5cee96e15a629025
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.4.0.jar
```

*UPDATE*: I just tried with Impala, and It neither sees anything:

```
➜  ~  impala-shell                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:1049: UserWarning: /home/itam/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extracti
on_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
Connected to 6b512e41337d:21000
Server version: impalad version 2.2.0-cdh5 RELEASE (build 2ffd73a4255cefd521362ffe1cfb37463f67f75c)
Welcome to the Impala shell. Press TAB twice to see a list of available commands.

Copyright (c) 2012 Cloudera, Inc. All rights reserved.

(Shell build version: Impala Shell v2.2.0-cdh5 (2ffd73a) built on Tue Apr 21 12:09:21 PDT 2015)
[6b512e41337d:21000] > invalidate metadata;
Query: invalidate metadata
[6b512e41337d:21000] > show tables;
Query: show tables

Fetched 0 row(s) in 0.00s
```

but from `beeline`:

```
~  beeline -u jdbc:hive2://
scan complete in 2ms
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.1.0-cdh5.4.0)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.1.0-cdh5.4.0)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.4.0 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://> show tables;
OK
+-----------+--+
| tab_name  |
+-----------+--+
| ufos      |
+-----------+--+
1 row selected (0.701 seconds)
```

It worked... What is happening?

*UPDATE*: I am running `hcatalog` too

```
➜  ~  sudo service hive-webhcat-server status
 * WEBHCat server is running

➜  ~  hcat -e "desc ufos"                    
OK
timestamp               string                  from deserializer   
city                    string                  from deserializer   
state                   string                  from deserializer   
shape                   string                  from deserializer   
duration                string                  from deserializer   
summary                 string                  from deserializer   
posted                  string                  from deserializer   
Time taken: 1.314 seconds
```

*UPDATE*: The problem with `impala` was due that I didn't copy `hive-site.xml` to `/etc/impala/conf`, once this is done, `impala-shell` worked properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loader you are using is deprecated. Instead of using `org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader`, you need to use `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader`.

From [org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader](http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/hcatalog/hcatalog-pig-adapter/org/apache/hcatalog/pig/HCatLoader.html):

> Deprecated. 
>   Use/modify [HCatLoader](http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/hcatalog/hcatalog-pig-adapter/org/apache/hive/hcatalog/pig/HCatLoader.html) instead

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the issue in HDP 2.3 and Pig 0.15 .

Package name for HCatLoader() class is different in Hortonworks distribution.

The following worked for me

USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader()

instead of 
 USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

Answer (score 0):

like you started to see the issues you have is with `hive-site.xml`file - you need to place it in the classpath

As mention [here](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_HCatalogIntegration.html):

> A workflow action interacting with HCatalog requires the following
> jars in the classpath: hcatalog-core.jar, webhcat-java-client.jar,
> hive-common.jar, hive-exec.jar, hive-metastore.jar, hive-serde.jar and
> libfb303.jar. hive-site.xml which has the configuration to talk to the
> HCatalog server also needs to be in the classpath. The correct version
> of HCatalog and hive jars should be placed in classpath based on the
> version of HCatalog installed on the cluster.
>
> The jars can be added to the classpath of the action using one of the
> below ways.
>
> - You can place the jars and hive-site.xml in the system shared library.
>   The shared library for a pig, hive or java action can be overridden to
>   include hcatalog shared libraries along with the action's shared
>   library. Refer to Shared Libraries for more information. The
>   oozie-sharelib-[version].tar.gz in the oozie distribution bundles the
>   required HCatalog jars in a hcatalog sharelib. If using a different
>   version of HCatalog than the one bundled in the sharelib, copy the
>   required HCatalog jars from such version into the sharelib.
> - You can
>   place the jars and hive-site.xml in the workflow application lib/
>   path.
> - You can specify the location of the jar files in archive tag and
>   the hive-site.xml in file tag in the corresponding pig, hive or java
>   action.

If you are going to use Oozie coordinator, upload them to HDFS coordinator path